# Interactive Text Area with Strict Guidelines

Tags: html

I'm trying to build an interactive text area where a user must enter specific text.

So for example I may ask a user to enter the answer to 'Does a dog bark?' If the user enters 'Yes' the box will turn green and if they enter anything else the box will turn red (green indicating correct and red indicating wrong).

I hope that is clear? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? (We're not here to do all the work - you need to have at least attempted to solve this yourself after reading the relevant documentation.)

Comment: I've got as far as having an actual text area as well as having text displayed in it that a user need to add to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in HTML. The closest you can get is to use the `pattern` attribute on an `input` element, as in `<input pattern=Yes>`. But the handling of valid vs. invalid input will then be at the hands of the browser, if it supports this attribute. Any controlled styling and/or functional handling of valid vs. invalid input needs to be handled with CSS and/or JavaScript or server-side form handlers.

If you define where the handling should take place, the problem becomes tractable. Note that if you check the input client-side, the correct answer will be visible to any user who views the source code (though you can try to obfuscate it).

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction of what I should be using?